# What's Julia's equivalent named vector in R?

Tags: julia

In `R`, we could give names to each items in a vector:

```
> x = c( 2.718 , 3.14 , 1.414 , 47405 )            # define the vector
> names(x) = c( "e" , "pi" , "sqrt2" , "zipcode" ) # name the components
> x[c(2,4)]                   # which indices to include
pi zipcode
3.14 47405.00
> x[c(-1,-3)]                 # which indices to exclude
pi zipcode
3.14 47405.00
> x[c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)] # for each position, include it?
pi zipcode
3.14 47405.00
```

In `Julia`, my first thought is using a `Dict`:

```
julia> x = [2.718, 3.14, 1.414, 47405]
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
     2.718
     3.14 
     1.414
 47405.0  

julia> namelist = ["e", "pi", "sqrt2", "zipcode"]
4-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "e"      
 "pi"     
 "sqrt2"  
 "zipcode"

julia> xdict=Dict(zip(namelist, x))
Dict{ASCIIString,Float64} with 4 entries:
  "e"       => 2.718
  "zipcode" => 47405.0
  "pi"      => 3.14
  "sqrt2"   => 1.414

julia> xdict["pi"]
3.14
```

However, `Dict` lost the order of the original array, meaning I cannot access items like in `R`:

```
julia> xdict[[2,4]]
ERROR: KeyError: [2,4] not found in getindex at dict.jl:718
```

Is there something like named array in `Julia`? If not, what's the Julia-way to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: you might want to take a look at `OrderedDict` in the DataStructures package https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl

Comment: also, `NamedArrays` are intended exactly for this. see the package at https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to replicate the R code using `NamedArrays`:

```
julia> using NamedArrays

julia> xx = NamedArray([2.718, 3.14, 1.414, 47405],
                       (["e", "pi", "sqrt2", "zipcode"],))
4-element NamedArrays.NamedArray...
e       2.718  
pi      3.14   
sqrt2   1.414  
zipcode 47405.0

julia> xx[[2,4]]
2-element NamedArrays.NamedArray...
pi      3.14   
zipcode 47405.0

julia> xx[setdiff(1:end,[1,3])]
2-element NamedArrays.NamedArray...
pi      3.14   
zipcode 47405.0

julia> xx[[1:end...][[false,true,false,true]]]
2-element NamedArrays.NamedArray...
pi      3.14   
zipcode 47405.0
```

The indexing techniques are less than optimal. **Improvements are welcome in the comments**. It is also possible to enhance `NamedArrays` easily for better indexing (which would be harder in R).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the last one: (filter by booleans) `xx[[1:end...][[false,true,false,true]]]`. (1) It seems to filter twice? What does the `...` in `1:end...` do? (2) Is it worked like a continuous  *chained* filters, like `xx[first-filter-cond] [second-filter-cond]`? (Maybe like the `data.table` package in `R`?

Comment: The first `[1: ]` defines a vector of all indices with the `...` being a short way to convert the `Range` to a vector. The second `[false, etc]` subsets the indices to give only the desired ones. This is possible since normal vectors allow subsetting with a boolean vector. The result is then used as the indices to `xx`. There might be better ways to do this - not sure.

Comment: So the syntax is `xx[ [_][_] ]` I am confused with the usage of outer pair of `[ ]`, which *seems* a black magic. I tried `xx[_][_]`, it doesn't work. Is it the inner two `[_][_]` produce an array, and the outer `[ ]` subset it?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. There is `xx[ A ]` where `A` is of the form `B[C]` and B is `[1:end...]` and C is `[false,true,false,true]`. Which subsets `B` with the vector `C` to create a vector `A` which subsets `xx`. It seemed simpler at first.

Answer (score 3):

Julia has the named tuple, which is a similar data structure that you can create like this:

`(e=2.718, pi=3.14159, sqrt2 = 1.44, zipcode=47405)`

(Do note that unlike named lists, named tuples are immutable. This leads to better performance, but means named tuples can be a bit of a pain to work with unless you use BangBang.jl, a package that lets you work with immutable objects as if they were mutable.)