# Julia - Is it possible to efficiently index into a vector by symbol

Tags: julia

Is it possible to efficiently index into a vector using symbol names?  And what would be the implementation?

```
data = [1, 2, 3]
names = [:a, :b, :c]

# access like
data[:a] # should show 1
```

Comment: Consider also a dictionary

Comment: Have a look at [What's Julia's equivalent named vector in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561641)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several packages that provide this functionality. I typically use NamedArrays.jl:

```
julia> using NamedArrays

julia> x = NamedArray([1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, :c])
3-element Named Vector{Int64}
A  │
───┼──
a  │ 1
b  │ 2
c  │ 3

julia> x[:a]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at *named tuple*:

```
data = (a=1, b=2, c=3)

data[:a]  #The value of the element named a
#1

data[1]  #The value of the first element
#1
```